# Bonita open studio schedule task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, business-process-management

I have a bonita open studio project working great.

Now, I don't know how to schedule the process to run daily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

- Put a Timer in the pool.
- Add a transition from the Timer to the Step.

Finaly config the timer for run daily:

- Click the timer
- Go to "General"
- Press "Edit.." in "Timer Condition"
- Press "Finish" buttom